# Getting Exception in FTPS (Talend)

Tags: talend

tFTPConnection got established perfectly

but when using tFTPGet I am getting this exception

```
Exception in component tFTPGet_1
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException [code=450, message= TLS session of 
data connection has not resumed or the session does not match the control connection]
```

Comment: I think this may be resolved by changing your tFTPGet the security mode setting (towards the bottom).  Which mode are you currently using?

Comment: Security mode:Implicit

Comment: If I use Security mode: explicit (Then I get java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out...)

Comment: my next step would be to run a wireshark trace.  are you familiar with wireshark?  it's generally east to setup and use, but you may have issues due to traffic encryption.  I would still try it though.  It may help you determine if its a firewall or proxy issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your FTP Server requires [TLS Session Resumption (RFC5077)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077).

Unfortunately, ftp4j seems to not support this feature.  Since tFTPGet is a wrapper for this library, I don't think there is something you can do to make it work.

Since ftp4j is not in active development (currently, [the last release is dated 2012](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ftp4j/files/ftp4j/)), I do not think this will be supported in the meantime.  Talend should choose a new library for FTP file transfers.

If you have control of this FTP Server, you may change it to not require TLS Session Resumption.  This thread at FileZilla forums discuss a little the risks of this change: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=36903